# string to list conversion

Tags: php

I am returning to Lisp after a number of years, when Common Lisp was just a twinkle in a computer scientist's eye! My experience of Lisp is primarily of lists (using setq, cdr and cadr functions, for example). After much head-scratching, I managed to read in a line of text from the keyboard, using 'read-line' but then discovered it was a string. Sooooo, is there a function that will convert (say) "THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT" to (THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simon
Scotland

Comment: `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`

Comment: what is the `(string1 string2)` dialect in LISP mean? array of string?

Comment: (string1 string2) is a LIST in LISP. Something like array...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, `(string string1 string2)` mean array of string in LISP. In that case, you want to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$explodedArray = explode(" ", $yourLongString);
var_dump($explodedArray);
foreach($explodedArray as $strEach){
    echo $strEach . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert the string to array

```
$array = explode(" ",$inputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood you correctly and you want, in PHP, from input string `THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT` get the output string `(THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT)` then this should just be fine:

```
<?php
    $inputStr = 'THE CAT SAT ON THE MAT';
    $outputStr = '('. $inputStr .')';
    echo $outputStr;
?>
```

**edit:**
Now, when I see that the (str str) is a list then this should work:

```
<?php
    $outputArray = explode(" ",$inputStr); 
?>
```

and the var_dump of the $outputArray variable will be:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=>
        string(3) "THE"
    [1]=>
        string(3) "CAT"
    [2]=>
        string(3) "SAT"
    [3]=>
        string(2) "ON"
    [4]=>
        string(3) "THE"
    [5]=>
        string(3) "MAT"
}
```

Comment: I don't thing he mean it literally.

Comment: @ariefbayu: Ah, I think you're right - but then again, he should provide more info :(